# Is an abelian $C^*-$ algebra an $AM-$ space?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-lattices

First, I remark some definitions:

Given $E$ a normed vector lattice, if the norm on $E$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
\|x \vee y\| = sup(\|x\|,\|y\|) \quad (x,y \in E_+),
\end{equation*}
then $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ is called an $M-$ normed space, and an $M-$ normed Banach lattice is called an abstract $M-$space, or $AM-$space.
If the norm satisfies
\begin{equation*}
\|x + y \| = \|x \| + \|y\| \quad (x,y \in E_+),
\end{equation*}
then $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ is called an $L-$ normed space, and an $L-$ normed Banach lattice is called an abstract $L-$ space, or $AL-$space.

($E_+$ denotes the cone of positive elements on $E$).

Also, AM- and AL- spaces are dual to each other in the following sense:

The dual of each $M-$ normed space is an $AL-$ space, and the dual of each $L-$ normed space is an $AM-$ space with unit.

A famous result stated by Kakutani says the following:

Let $E$ be an $AM-$ space with unit and denote by $K$ the weak*- compact set of REAL valued lattice homomorphisms of norm one on $E$. The evaluation map $x \mapsto f$ (where $f(t) = \langle x,t \rangle \,, \, t \in K$), is an isomorphism of $E$ into $C(K)$.

Now I'm wondering, an abelian $C^*-$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is isomorphic to $C(K)$ where $K$ is its spectrum, a *-weak compact subset of $\mathcal{A}^*$ of norm one COMPLEX-valued homomorphisms, and with these results at hand, I would be tempted to say that any abelian $C^*-$ Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is an $AM-$ space, as a clear consequence of Gelfand-Naimark isomorphism and Kakutani.\ 
This means that the dual space $\mathcal{A}$ is an $AL-$space. Indeed, for positive linear functionals $f_1,f_2 \in \mathcal{A}^*$, one obtains
\begin{equation*}
\|f_1 + f_2\| = (f_1 + f_2)(e)=f_1(e)+f_2(e) = \|f_1\| + \|f_2\|,
\end{equation*}
using that $\|f\|=f(e)$.

Can I say this? I observe that Kakutani holds for real valued maps. The point would be saying that it holds for the complexification of the lattice, but I'm not sure..

EDIT:

Ok I figured out some considerations about this question and I'm editing now to post them.
In general, despite satisfying the norm- additivity on the cone of positive elements, the dual of a general(not abelian) $C^*-$ algebra is NOT an AL-space.
Indeed, if I take a positive functional $f : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, its absolute value $|f|$ cannot be determined uniquely and this is a consequence of the not uniqueness of extension provided by the Hahn Banach theorem. So the dual space of a generic $C^*-$ algebra satisfies the AL- axiom but it is NOT an AL- space since it is just not a lattice. Indeed, if one assumed the dual of a generic $C^*-$ algebra to be AL- space, then by the duality results of AL/AM, its dual would be an AM-space, and again by Kakutani, it would be isomorphic to a C(K). But this is clearly impossible, since the bidual $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ (Enveloping von neumann algebra of $\mathcal{A}$) is clearly not commutative, in general.

Instead if we take into account a commutative $C^*-$ algebra C(X), then by kakutani and gelfand-naimark one can easily say that its self-adjoint part $\mathcal{A}_{sa}$ is isomorphic to some AM-space and in this case, its dual IS an AL-space. In fact, in this situation the uniqueness of absolute value is provided by the well-known Jordan decomposition of measure $|\mu| = \mu^+ + \mu^-$.

So the answer to the original question is : no, but its self-adjoint part is.

Hope this will be useful to someone (and correct ^_^").

Comment: Not entirely sure where you are going. You don't need Kakutani here: you can check directly, via Gelfand-Naimark and you computation on the dual, that any abelian C$^*$-algebra is an AM space.

Comment: please could you show me exactly what you mean? I was thinking of Kakutani because it clearly establishes an isomorphism between $C(K)$ and an AM-space but in this case it is specified that K is the set of real-valued homomorphisms. So since a $C^*$ algebra isn't real, in general, I was thinking that maybe it was isomorphic to the self-adjonint part. But could you show me formally what you meant? Thank you for the answer

Comment: No, you are right. The problem is that things are not real. I don't even know what the join is in  $C (K) $.

Comment: I would just need to know if Kakutani still holds when I consider the complexification of a Banach Lattice $E$.

Comment: I just don't know about this. What would $f\vee g$ be when $f,g$ are not real?

Comment: I figured this out. I’m going to edit my question with few considerations I made these days. Thanks for your interest

Comment: @MartinArgerami I added some considerations I made about this problem. Not 100% sure they are totally correct, but I'd like to have your opinion about them. Unfortunately I didn't find many resources about this question online. Thanks again